# Select data from 1 column based on multiple conditions in 2nd column

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, window-functions

I need to exclude all IDs that have the color green in them.

| ID | Colors_Allowed |
| --- | --- |
| 555 | Blue |
| 555 | Green |
| 666 | Blue |
| 786 | Blue |
| 888 | Blue |
| 888 | Green |
| 888 | Red |
| 999 | Red |
| 999 | Orange |

**Expected result**:

| ID | Colors_allowed |
| --- | --- |
| 666 | Blue |
| 786 | Blue |
| 999 | Red |
| 999 | Orange |

Here's the attempt I've made:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE colors_allowed != 'Green'
```

But this also gives me ids "*555*" and "*888*" with colors other than green, which I don't want since they had the color green, and that should have disqualified them.

Comment: which SQL are you using? MS SQL Server, MySQL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use INNER subquery to find ID having color Green and using outer query with NOT IN clause to select ID which does not have Green in it.

Demo query - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2848d/1

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Colors_Allowed
FROM TableName
WHERE ID NOT IN  ( SELECT ID
                   FROM TableName
                   WHERE Colors_Allowed = 'Green');
```

Comment: But it missed some IDs of Blue and Red having IDs 888 and 999 respectively. It should provide all colors with all IDs except Green.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAnwar- You can check the link for results which is matching as expected output. 888 would not show up as it has Green color with Id 888. Id 999 is showing up in the result set because it doesn't contain green color. If you have downvoted for this reason then understand the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        max(case when colors_allowed = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by id) has_green
    from mytable t
) t
where has_green = 0
```

The conditional `max()` checks all rows that have the same `id` as the current row, and yields `1` if any has color green. The outer query uses this information for filtering.

The upside of the window function technique is that it requires a single table scan (as opposed to self-joins, `exists` and `in`).

Comment: Thanks GMB.

I was able to accomplish the task by writing a subquery.

But thank you for giving the window functions way of doing it. Definitely will ready up on this so my code becomes more efficient. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the `NOT EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tab t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM tab t2 
                 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID AND colors_allowed = 'Green')
```

This checks when there's no record of the same id `t1.ID = t2.ID` having at least one "*Green*" value.

**Output**:

| ID | Colors_Allowed |
| --- | --- |
| 666 | Blue |
| 786 | Blue |
| 999 | Red |
| 999 | Orange |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zPR21sFO).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
indata(ID,Colors_Allowed) AS (
          SELECT 555,'Blue'
UNION ALL SELECT 555,'Green'
UNION ALL SELECT 666,'Blue'
UNION ALL SELECT 786,'Blue'
UNION ALL SELECT 888,'Blue'
UNION ALL SELECT 888,'Green'
UNION ALL SELECT 888,'Red'
UNION ALL SELECT 999,'Red'
UNION ALL SELECT 999,'Orange'
)
-- REAL query starts here -replace following comma with "WITH" ..
, 
green AS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM indata
  WHERE colors_allowed='Green'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM indata
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM green)
;
```

| ID | Colors_Allowed |
| --- | --- |
| 666 | Blue |
| 786 | Blue |
| 999 | Red |
| 999 | Orange |